# Repercussions of misclassifying variable type during correlation determination?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation, categorical-data, continuous-data

I have multiple variables like as below

a) Product Ids (input - nominal/ordinal) # This column has repeated values (though the ids are specific for a product)

b) Product Type (input - nominal)

c) Quantity (input - numeric)

d) Business Status (output - Binary/discrete containing win or loss)

While I found the table below from link [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/statistics-in-python-using-anova-for-feature-selection-b4dc876ef4f0) (ignore the red highlight box)

[image]

I have two questions

a) Can I check with you on what is the impact of considering a ordinal variable as continuous? Or treating a ordinal variable as nominal or vice-versa? Because, I feel that is purely dependent on the person who analyzes the data. But misclassifying the variables and using corresponding tests as per above table, can lead to spurious results?

b) can share any other detailed resources which will have such table info for different correlation methods to use depending on variable type? For ex: In the below, we have the technique for continuous input and categorical output missing. Point bisserial correlation?? Can help me share such detailed resource, so I can bookmark it

c) I guess if we interchange variable 1 and variable 2, the same tests apply for correlation. right to understand that?

Comment: It's a thoughtful set of questions.  But I can't help remarking that statistical theory pays almost no attention to variable type as a potential determiner of an appropriate procedure to apply.  Consequently, looking for guidance of this sort will likely doom you to a diet of "cheat sheets" created by teachers to help students pass tests, rather than opening up avenues toward deeper understanding.

Comment: So, you suggest that I experiment with multiple correlation procedures, compare the results, understand the difference. But how do I choose the final one? Or if the results are same across multiple techniques, just take one at random. There can never be one sure shot method?

Comment: A better suggestion would be to study a beginning textbook on statistical inference: the good ones explain the principles that are really used to create good statistical procedures and select appropriate ones in a given problem.  Many such books are listed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363.

Comment: @whuber - can I seek your help with this ONLY if you have time? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559165/how-to-know-if-i-have-enough-controllable-info-for-ml-modelling